# How to exclude a filter from a facet?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have come from a Solr background and am trying to find the equivalent of ["tagging" and "excluding"](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SimpleFacetParameters#Tagging_and_excluding_Filters) in Elasticsearch.

In the following example, how can I exclude the `price` filter from the calculation of the `prices` facet? In other words, the `prices` facet should take into account all of the filters except for `price`.

```
{
  query : {
    "filtered" : {
      "query" : {
        "match_all" : {}
      },
      "filter" : {
        "and" : [
          {
            "term" : {
              "colour" : "Red"
            }
          },
          {
            "term" : {
              "feature" : "Square"
            }
          },
          {
            "term" : {
              "feature" : "Shiny"
            }
          },
          {
            "range" : {
              "price" : { 
                "from" : "10",
                "to" : "20"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "facets" : {
    "colours" : {
      "terms" : {
        "field" : "colour"
      }
    },
    "features" : {
      "terms" : {
        "field" : "feature"
      }
    },
    "prices" : {
      "statistical" : {
        "field" : "price"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can apply price filter as a top level filter to your query and add it to all facets expect prices as a facet_filter:

```
{
  query : {
    "filtered" : {
      "query" : {
        "match_all" : {}
      },
      "filter" : {
        "and" : [
          {
            "term" : {
              "colour" : "Red"
            }
          },
          {
            "term" : {
              "feature" : "Square"
            }
          },
          {
            "term" : {
              "feature" : "Shiny"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "facets" : {
    "colours" : {
      "terms" : {
        "field" : "colour"
      },
      "facet_filter" : {
        "range" : { "price" : {  "from" : "10", "to" : "20" } }
      }
    },
    "features" : {
      "terms" : {
        "field" : "feature"
      },
      "facet_filter" : {
        "range" : { "price" : {  "from" : "10", "to" : "20" } }
      }
    },
    "prices" : {
      "statistical" : {
        "field" : "price"
      }
    }
  },
  "filter": {
    "range" : { "price" : {  "from" : "10", "to" : "20" } }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid this does not seem to work. The `price` filter is not applied to the search results. Also, the `price` filter is still included in the calculation of the `prices` facet.

Comment: Thank you, that works perfectly. There was a problem with the way I was nesting the query. Just one final thought: is there a way to achieve this without the duplication? I have lots of facets, so adding `facet_filter` to every other facet is far from ideal.

Comment: Yes, it's not ideal, but at the moment that's the only solution that I can think of. Starting with 0.90, there are really only 3 ways to control what you see in facets vs filters: filtered query (affects both facets and results), top level filter (affects only results) and facet_filter (affects only facets).

Answer (score 0):

Btw, important change since ES 1.0.0. Top-level filter was renamed to post_filter (http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/_search_requests.html#_search_requests). And filtered queries using is still preferred as described here: http://elasticsearch-users.115913.n3.nabble.com/Filters-vs-Queries-td3219558.html

And there is `global` option for facets to avoid filtering by query filter (elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-facets.html#_scope).